# Tinymce5 - How to add an external toolbar for classic editor?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-5

I want to integrate tinymce without using inline editor. There are several sections where each section act as editor instances (keep data separately). Is there a way to add a toolbar to an external container using classic editor without using inline editor?

I need a single toolbar for all sections in an external container. I know that tinymce provide inline editor option with external toolbar container, but it creates multiple toolbars for each editor instance.

Answer (score 0):

Our recommendation to achieve this functionality, generally, is to use the editor(s) in inline mode, and use the fixed_tool_bar_container option:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#fixed_toolbar_container

Using this option would render the toolbar in the same location regardless of which editor instance was clicked into.

Caveats with this method are that the toolbar doesn't render until an editor is clicked, and the toolbar disappears when clicking out of an editor.

Here is a Tiny Fiddle demo:
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Mphaab